# Minipage not centered in tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, minipage

I tried half a dozen solutions I found for "minipage not centerd", none worked. Maybe the minipage is not the problem, I am not sure. Anyway, I want to get this deduction rule centered in the tikz node:

[image]

My code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[below, draw] {
  \begin{minipage}{4em}
    \scriptsize
    \begin{prooftree}
      \AxiomC{$A\land B$}
      \UnaryInfC{$B$}
    \end{prooftree}
  \end{minipage}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Any suggestion or idea what the problem is?

Comment: The line break after `\node[below, draw] {` causes a space being added here which pushes the `minipage` to the right. Try it with `\node[below, draw] {%` (the `%` removes the line break as a comment).

Comment: Actually that has no effect in this case.

Comment: If you use `text width=4em` TikZ uses a minipage environment anyhow for the contents.

Comment: @Io Ok, I wasn't sure if `\node` removes spaces at the beginning and end or not. Apparently it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

desired result can be obtained without use of `minipage` and `bussproofs`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw, text width=4em, align=center, font=\scriptsize] {
    $\dfrac{A\land B}{B}$
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**addendum:** for cases that `bussproofs` is very necessary, you can help you with the following dirty heck:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node[below, draw, inner xsep=0pt, font=\scriptsize] {
  \begin{minipage}{5em}%                <--- (% sign had to be here)
    \begin{prooftree}\hspace*{-1ex}%    <--- (% sign had to be here)
      \AxiomC{$A\land B$}
      \UnaryInfC{$B$}
    \end{prooftree}
  \end{minipage}
};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
pf/.style = {draw, 
             text width=#1, 
             align=center, inner xsep=0pt, font=\scriptsize}
                        ]
  \node[pf=5em] {\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
    \begin{prooftree}\hspace*{-1ex}%
      \AxiomC{$A\land B$}
      \UnaryInfC{$B$}
    \end{prooftree}
                };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

both examples gives:

[image]

edit: with `beamer` document class in case of use tikz nodes with option, yyyyou should add option `fragile` to the frame:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{centering bussproofs relation in tikz node}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
pf/.style = {draw,
             text width=#1,
             align=center, inner xsep=0pt, font=\scriptsize}
                        ]
  \node[pf=5em] {\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
    \begin{prooftree}\hspace*{-1ex}%
      \AxiomC{$A\land B$}
      \UnaryInfC{$B$}
    \end{prooftree}
                };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: sure, but I have more complicated expressions that do require bussproofs and have the same issue.

Comment: @lotolmencre, i'm not familiar with `bussproofs`, but from showed examples i doubt that it is more powerful than standard math packages.  anyway, i add some heck which  maybe will help you.

Comment: Thanks, any idea what might be in your code that does not work in beamer frames? When I put it in a beamer frame environment I get `Illegal parameter number in definition of \test.`

Comment: @lotolmencre, you not mentioned, that used documentclaa is `beamer` :-). try `\begin{frame}[fragile]\frametitle{ title } ... \end{frame}`.  in editor `\end{frame} hadn't have empty space before it (older beamer version). check if  version of your `beamer` is recent (3.44 2017-11-10). if not, please upgrade it.

Comment: @lotolmencre, i add example of my answer with `beamer` document class.